# How to Create Two Similar Methods in the Business Layer of a Structured Architecture with Minimal Redundancy?

Tags: oop, methods, architecture, clean-architecture

The structure of my application is layered. The GUI is handled by Controllers, the Controllers each have a Service (which is responsible for business logic). For context, when a button is pressed, there is a method in the Controller that calls the respective method from the Service, in addition to other GUI-related stuff.

My question is, if I need to have the methods "Create copy of excel and open it" and "Only create copy of excel" in Service, how can I minimize the redundancy of the 2 methods?

Also, if I choose to write these 2 methods separately in Service, in the Controller there will also need to exist 2 methods with similar names to those in Service, each of them containing a single line of code that calls the respective method from Service. How can I write this code as clean as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two methods:

```
CreateCopyOfExcel(/*...*/)

OpenExcel(/*...*/)
```

If you want to create a copy of Excel and open it, call both in sequence:

```
CreateCopyOfExcel(/*...*/);
OpenExcel(/*...*/);
```

If you you only want to create the copy, call only that method:

```
CreateCopyOfExcel(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

Was going to make this a comment on @Mark's but it got too long:

@Mark above is right, that is the easiest path forward.   But a couple pieces of advice:

1. There is no reason a service method can't call another service method.  So have your `OpenACopyOfExcel()` method call your `CreateACopyOfExcel()` method on your service.
2. Don't make your services automatically a 1-1 for your controllers.  The goal is to model business capabilities in your service layer, and UI invocation of those business capabilities in your controller layer.   If you find yourself writing these 1-1 all the time, then you probably haven't modeled your domain separately from your UI.
3. Have a care that you don't have UI concerns leaking into you Service layer.  The Service layer isn't "Opening" an excel file. It can't.  That's a UI concern, it could provide a stream to an open file, a file handle, or something similar, but it shouldn't be able to do anything user-facing.  I generally try and think about it like this: "Could I invoke this method on a command line with no UI and have it make sense?"  No references to buttons, input boxes, our output targets, just data in and data out.